# Apache Virtual Host Server Error while Restarting

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I will login my Server through root User on PuTTy and Install LAMP on it. After Installing Lamp, on **Centos 7** i will make Apache Virtual Host Successfully, but at last when i will try to restart the Apache, it show's an error. How to solve this issue?

```
systemctl status httpd.service

**Error=>>>>>>>**

● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server

Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)

Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-08-24 11:38:04 EDT; 10s ago

Docs: man:httpd(8)

        man:apachectl(8)

Process: 7029 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, 

status=1/FAILURE)

  Process: 7028 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, 

status=1/FAILURE)

 Main PID: 7028 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 24 11:38:04 example.com systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...

Aug 24 11:38:04 example.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exite...E

Aug 24 11:38:04 example.com kill[7029]: kill: cannot find process ""

Aug 24 11:38:04 example.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process ex...1

Aug 24 11:38:04 example.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP S....

Aug 24 11:38:04 example.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed....

Aug 24 11:38:04 example.com systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.

Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: Does a `configtest` report an issue? On FreeBSD you can check with `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/apache24 configtest`

Comment: I have Centos 7 OS on my Server

Answer (score 0):

### Always start with a troubleshooting effort.

This command will show you what caused the error:

#### On CentOS with Apache, please use

```
apachectl -t
```

#### On Ubuntu with Apache2, please use

```
apache2ctl -t
```

Normally this maybe a very minor error(s), fix the error, restart the apache web server and enjoy.

Happy coding.